# Rack dependency and thin start

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rack, thin

I am trying to use thin to serve a Ruby on Rails application on a Windows host.

When I run

```
thin start
```

I get the following error:

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-    1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:33:in `block in setup': You have already activated rack 1.5.0, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.4.5. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)

After I try to resolve the dependency by running:

```
gem install rack -v 1.4.5
```

I get the following error:

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247: in `to_specs': Could not find rack (>= 1.5.0) amongst...[list of installed gems].

I take it that the problem is that thin requires rack 1.5.0 but that my project requires rack 1.4.5.  How can I resolve this and get thin to start correctly?  I am new to Rails and somewhat confused about what to do.

I don't want to add thin to my bundle and use bundle exec because the project does not require thin itself - I just want to use it as an application server.

Is it possible to install the two versions of rack side by side?  Alternatively, how can I upgrade my project to use rack 1.5.0 so that it uses the same version required by thin?  I am running thin 1.6.0, Rails 3.2.9 and Ruby 1.9.3.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your Gemfile, by adding `gem 'rack', '1.5.0'` and removing the existing rack entry. If you have updated Rack to another version than 1.5.0, in the meantime, then just do `gem 'rack'` or `gem 'rack', '"your_version"'`.